# save chosen file, when form validation fails

Tags: php, forms, validation, file-upload

I've got a form with some input fiels. One of them is a file upload field.
When the user submits the form, every field will be validated and the page gets reloaded with the error messages, but all other fields still showing the users input. Now I want, that once a user has chosen a file, and the form can't be validated because of other errors, the chosen file still will be uploaded after a resubmission.

I display the entered values with the value property. I know that you can't set the value of an file input, because of security issues.

This is what I've got so far:

```
<?php
if(isset($fileUpload)) 
{
    echo "<span>selected File: ".$fileUpload["name"]."<span>";
    $_FILES["file-upload"]=$fileUpload;
} ?>
<input type="file" class="button" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" accept=".zip"/>
```

This happens after submission:

```
if (!isset($_FILES["file-upload"]))
{
    $uploadError = "Please choose a file";
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $fileUpload=$_FILES["file-upload"];   
}
```

The submitted file is stored in `$fileUpload`. I tried to set the `$_FILES["file-upload"]` variable manually, but it doesn't seem to work.
After resubmission, `$fileUpload["name"]` is empty.

How can I save the selected file, so the user hasn't to reselect it after an unsuccessful submission?

Comment: It’s 2015. Form validation mustn’t be done with page reload. Use ajax whether you need to check it server-side, but please do not reload the whole page.

Comment: That's true. But it can still be done with page reload. There might be reasons for it, so this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

You cant store the file value after loading page like other fields ( the other way is you can upload the file and in return you can pass the uploaded file value in hidden , if user add file again the unlink the previous file otherwise the use the file which uploaded in first step. )

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to use a hidden field. Thanks for this input

Comment: @j0h4nn3s like answer so that others can check this :)